# Error estimate for the position of a maximum given data

Tags: error-analysis

Alright, so I am not sure what terminology easily describes this, but I have an excel spreadsheet with data for plotting a graph, and I know that there is a maximum in this graph, and I am trying to estimate its position. So what I wonder is given the uncertainties in the measurements of frequency and amplitude in this case, how can I find the uncertainty in the position of the maximum? I could just use the point with the greatest amplitude, but we do not know whether or not a better maximum exists. I could say that assuming there is only one maximum (which we may do), I could use the points around the top maximum to create a range in which the maximum should lie, but then I still have no quantitative deciding on the uncertainty. I hope I am being sufficiently descriptive here, but I am not sure. I suppose another question is what we use as our best estimate for the maximising frequency anyways.

To be clear, I do have access to errors in all measured quantities on the graph.

[image: graph]

I added a copy of this question to Cross Validated SE:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/340512/error-estimate-for-the-position-of-a-maximum-given-data

Comment: I assume this is the best exchange to post this question on?

Comment: No I think Cross Validated SE would be better, because you are asking about the statistical analysis of data rather than about any issue of physics.

Answer (score 0):

My idea on this issue is that we treat the different situations case by case, with respect to the maximum as shown on the graph.

For the low resonance case, for which there exists a single measurable maximum amplitude and corresponding frequency, we use the average of the closely distributed (almost coinciding) data points as the estimation. This comes from the arguments:

1. a measurable maximum (i. maximum amplitude within in the maximum range of the instrument; ii. vertical clustering observed <-> change in the amplitude due to the uncertainty in frequency measurements still allows clustering to happen) exists
2. the almost coinciding data points can be treated as multiple measuements for the same maxima point within our error range (a normal distribution for sure)

For the high resonance case, for which the maximum is not measurable within the error range and no vertical clustering is observed around the maximum, we use the average of the half amplitude points to roughly give an estimation. This comes from the arguments:

1. no measurable maximum exists
2. the half amplitude points are determined comparablly accurately from the envelope of points measured, and are a characterizing feature of the position of the maximum amplitude point due to symmetry. The uncertainty can be taken as the same as the frequency measurement, or appropriately scaled up to give more confidence.

Please do add on to this as this is just a roughly skecthed solution.

Comment: Alright, so what do we mean with a "measurable maximum," and how precisely are we getting, and using the half-amplitude points here?

Comment: Updated on the meaning of a "measurable maximum". The uncertanty for half-amplitude point method is a rough estimate and is mentioned in the 2nd argument of the relavent section.

Comment: I still do not entirely see how the half-amplitude points are being used/defined here. I don't measure half amplitude points on the graph. Is it meant that if we assume the peak is roughly symmetric, we take the average of points of comparable height?